# About the solr document position

Tags: solrj

I have a requirement：

Get 5 solr documents which after a specified solr document，
so I try use the solr parameter of `start` and `rows`；
but I do not know how to  confirm   the position of the specified document
in the documents.

Please Help！
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try sorting your results.  It will add a bit of overhead and might not be the best way to do it, but you'll get what you want.

This link should give you all the information you need.

http://yonik.com/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/